# Junit test gets NoSuchElementException but only on specific numbers

Tags: java, junit

I've written some code which inputs two numbers, and checks whether they are int, if not clears the keyboard input and then checks again.  This gets an NoSuchElementException under JUnit testing, but only on specific input values (5, not 0).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HasException {

    public int chooseNumber()
    {
     System.out.println("Enter a number, you can select 1 to 3");
        int number;
        do{
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!in.hasNextInt())    // when there isn't a integer next in the keyboard input
        {
            System.out.println("Not a number, please try again");
            String discardedString = in.next(); // empty the buffer
        }
        number =in.nextInt();
        if((number<1)||(number>3))
        {
            System.out.println("This is wrong choice, Please select 1 to 3");
        }
        }while((number<1)||(number>3));
        return number;
    }


}


import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;


public class HasExceptionTest {

public final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
public final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


HasException myHasException;    // declare the class to be tested

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));

    myHasException = new HasException();

}


@After
public void cleanUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(null);
    System.setErr(null);
}


@Test
public void test1() {   // this test fails with NoSuchElementException
    String input = "5" + "2";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);

    int result = myHasException.chooseNumber();  // exception NoSuchElementException here
    assertEquals(result, 2);
}

@Test
public void test2() {   // this test passes
    String input = "0" + "2";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);

    int result = myHasException.chooseNumber();
    assertEquals(result, 2);
}



}
```

Answer (score 3):

`String input = "0" + "2";` results in the value "02".

`String input = "5" + "2";` assigns "52" to input.

So you're only checking ONE value.

If you check for "02", it succeeds, you successfully exit chooseNumber(), and your test passes.  Yay.

If you input "52", however, chooseNumber() loops and tries to read another number from "input".

Since you only have *ONE* value ("52"), the second read FAILS.  With NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 1):

For "52" the chooseNumber() loop tries to get nextInt() in 2nd time and  getting exception. So you should use break when no next value.

chooseNumber() should look like below:
public class HasException {

```
public int chooseNumber() {
    System.out.println("Enter a number, you can select 1 to 3");
    int number = 0;
    do {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("log hasNext =" + in.hasNext());
        while (in.hasNext() && !in.hasNextInt()) // when there isn't a
                                                    // integer next in the
                                                    // keyboard input
        {
            System.out.println("log 2");

            System.out
                    .println("Not a number, please try again" + in.next());
            String discardedString = in.next(); // empty the buffer
        }

        if (!in.hasNext()) {
            break;
        }
        number = in.nextInt();

        if ((number < 1) || (number > 3)) {
            System.out
                    .println("This is wrong choice, Please select 1 to 3");
        }

    } while ((number < 1) || (number > 3));
    return number;
}
```

}

Comment: Hint: look into your naming skills. `HasException` is a really bad name for this class. This class asks the user for specific input. That has **nothing** todo with exceptions. Use names that **mean** something. Beyond that: when you **pass** a Scanner to this method; instead of creating a Scanner **fixed** to System.in, you would not need to do all that complicated setup. And your code would be a bit easier to re-use, too.